# Sequelize query where on children

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a User and a Country model. User belongs to many countries and vice-versa.
How can I query the user that only has a specific country ID in his `countries` array?

```
const users = await DB.User.findAll({
  where: {
    // What to put here?
  },
  include: [
    {
      model: DB.Country,
      as: 'countries',
      // Putting where here only causes the countries to filter
    },
  ],
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want any user having specific country, nothing to put in user's where clause, put the where clause in the country include section.

```
const users = await DB.User.findAll({
  where: {
    // Nothing to put here
  },
  include: [
    {
      model: DB.Country,
      as: 'countries',
      where:{
          id : YOUR_EXPECTED_COUNTRY_ID
      }
    },
  ],
});
```